# Is it appropriate to "rescue" good code from a self-deleted answer?

Tags: discussion

Consider the scenario: someone has posted an answer containing code that answers the question, but the person who posted that answer later deleted it, e.g., because the OP criticized it.  However, the code *does* answer the question, would solve the OPs problem, and be a valuable contribution to the site.

Would it be disrespectful to copy the code from the deleted answer and post it as community wiki, with attribution?  What, if anything, should be done in this situation?

*Original context: [Check windows user is standard or Administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28473968/check-windows-user-is-standard-or-administrator); but it turns out that the question has already been asked and answered elsewhere.  Also, the code in the deleted answer was copied from someone else's answer without attribution.*

Comment: I don't see how providing attribution could be considered "disrespectful" in any sense of the word.  I'd say do it.

Comment: @Makoto: the poster made the decision to delete his answer, so reposting the code *might* be seen as not respecting that decision.

Comment: They're posting the content under [CC-By-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) though.  I don't necessarily disagree with your viewpoint, it's just that the license has already provided the permission you require.

Comment: I think within the license it is certainly allowed, but that doesn't mean you *have* to duplicate it. If I have right of way on a crossing that doesn't mean I *have* to go first. If the answer was critisized by OP and therefor deleted, I would consider that a good reason not to repost its content, even though the site licenses allow it. "Disrespectful" might be a bit of a strong term, but yeah.

Comment: I prefer to vote-to-undelete such questions, and to get my friends and enemies to do the same.

Comment: Without actually knowing why it was deleted, it's hard to know if it's appropriate.  For instance, if someone accidentally posted proprietary code that they don't really want to CC license, re-posting it might not be a very nice thing to do.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You are certainly more than welcome to re-post the content, so long as you attribute it properly, yes.

By posting the content to SO they applied the CC-wiki licence to it, giving others the rights to redistribute the content or create derived works of it, so long as there is attribution.

Comment: It can be quite tricky to re-attribute it to a link to the deleted answer (since many users won't be able to see it).

Comment: @Bruno Yes, and given that I'd want to call out the author by name, and not just link to the answer.

Comment: This is interesting legally (or I would think.) Maybe someday we'll have a clause that says "unless you delete it within 10 minutes this is permanently binding" like a buyer's remorse clause.

Comment: @canon If they request it, they can choose to have their name disassociated with the content if they want, but they'd need to explicitly say so.  They of course can't revoke the right for the content to be re-distributed, only to have their name removed from the attribution.

Comment: @canon It's an exceptional enough case that I'm not really concerned about the need for moderator involvement.

Comment: @canon by the time the user clicks the submit button, it is already too late to worry about being associated to the posted content, ANYWHERE on the web (not only SE sites). The internet never really forgets, and a copy of the page with your content might be on someone's browser cache anyway.

Comment: @canon I am afraid that sphere is very thin, full of holes and small in diameter. The only manifestation of that sphere I know (in the subject at hand) is what kind of users have the privilege to view deleted content. I suppose that mods aside, its a very select group.

Comment: @canon I moved my further thoughts on the matter to a proper answer. I agree with you on the point that several users want to be rid of deleted content forever.

Answer (score 18):

That post was plagiarized from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6405799/17034).

So no.

Comment: Of course, _that_ answer can be copied now -- with attribution -- but the right move is apparently dupe closure.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: not to that question, though; they aren't duplicates.  One wants to know whether the user is an administrator, whether elevated or not, and the other wants to know whether the process is running with elevated privileges.

Comment: Fair enough, @HarryJohnston; I confess to having only skimmed both.

Comment: @Josh: D'oh!  The question itself contains a link to an answered duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

From the comment thread on this [answer above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285961/1532705), I want to add that while it is not disrespectful, if the user that deleted said answer is active on SE sites, it wouldn't hurt asking him if he wants to be attributed at all.

While you can (i.e. it is legally allowed due to the CC license) repost the answer with attribution, it is a case where a little communication can go a long way to avoid a misunderstanding.

As [@canon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/621962/canon) pointed, several users would be annoyed to see content they deleted reposted and attributed to them without prior notice.

Comment: There really isn't any way to communicate with the user though.  You cannot comment on the answer as it's deleted, and pinging them on your answer wouldn't notify them.

Comment: @Servy - unless user deleted *all* questions/answers/comments one can ask on some other question with enough info to point back (and delete in timely manner)... While it is not really ideal approach it may be nicer than repost someones else code (there could be many other reasons why answer is deleted - including not really license clean code or subtle errors - in addition to regular rage quit).

Comment: @Servy yes, unless he is in some SE chatroom... but you can always comment on some backwater (old and low-traffic) post, and the user will see it in the notifications bar. This way you can estabilish some communication. Just remember to delete them after you got in touch. Not the intended use for comments though

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to simultaneously respect *both* the OP and the answer-poster (at least in the matter of this question, to which they disagree); however, I'd re-post -- with proper attribution of course, as stated above.

Reason:  A timely stack-overflow answer may save someone minutes, hours, .... even their job (especially contractors).  Of course, if it is a known duplicate, that's different!

Answer (score -1):

As discussed, there doesn't seem to be a *legal* issue, but unlike most answerers here, I think it is indeed disrespectful in general. Yes, it is sad to lose a good answer because the answerer caved to ill-considered criticism, but that was their call.

One exception: if the answerer clearly deleted their answer because it was determined that it didn't quite get at the exact question the OP was aiming for, then it might well be reasonable and respectful to rescue it to answer a *different question*.

Comment: You could only do this if you realized that the answer was answering a different question, and knew what question the answer was *intending* to answer.  If you felt that it was answering the question asked, you couldn't post it to a different question, as they'd be duplicates.